# python threading: exit program when one of many threads fail

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to find a way to have a script exit when one of the threads fail.
I have experimented with `_thread.interrupt_main()` and `daemon = True` as follow:

```
import threading
import time
import _thread


def run1(x):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)


def run_and_stop(x):
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        i += 1
        if i == 5:
            _thread.interrupt_main()


t1 = threading.Thread(target = run1, args = ('a', ), daemon = True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = run1, args = ('b', ), daemon = True)
t3 = threading.Thread(target = run1, args = ('c', ), daemon = True)
t4 = threading.Thread(target = run_and_stop, args = ('d', ), daemon = True)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()

time.sleep(100)
```

Here the program should exit after 5s : the last thread reaches the `interrupt_main()` command, and since the other threads are daemon, they should all shut down then.

However it doesn't happen so. Can anyone explain me why and provide a solution for the program to exit then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, `time.sleep()` uses `select()`. We could interrupt it by signaling the process, or explicitly the main thread, via `kill()` or `pthread_kill()`.

As for `_thread.interrupt_main`, from [this discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue29926):

> "Looking at the implementation, _thread.interrupt_main just calls PyErr_SetInterrupt. It doesn’t appear to send a signal. I played with “strace” and couldn’t see any evidence of a signal. I guess it just sets a flag that will be polled. To actually interrupt the “sleep” call, you might need to use “pthread_kill” or similar (at least on Unix)."

```
def run_and_stop(x):
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        i += 1
        if i == 5:
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```